# Laravel 4.2, Swiftmailer and queues

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4, smtp

I am sending instant notification emails on my web application, and to stop the app hanging while it sends them, I am pushing them off too a queue. However I have started to get this message,

> [2015-12-16 23:32:16] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'fwrite(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:1409F07F:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_PENDING:bad write retry'

I have read up on this and it appears that the mail functionality does not cope well on daemon workers and it is loses connection to the SMTP server. I was wondering what solutions I could use to work around this?

Would sending the emails to their own specific queue help? In Laravel is there a way to reconnect to SMTP every email? I have added `YOzaz/Laravel-SwiftMailer` which overs a reset method but that does not seem change the error messages I am getting?

What are other peoples approaches to queueing email? Maybe I could run a CRON every minute that fires through a queue? My only prerequisites are that I use SMTP.

Any advice would be fantastic.